# Custom Slider Per Page created

Tags: customization, custom-post-types, php, plugins

I am developing a site that will need to have a slider with 4-8 images, but only on certain page-types.

These pages must be editable and the sliders must be able to be updated whenever I'd like.

I can easily do the slider and the page theme, it's just the dynamic slider area that is getting me.

I've been theming wordpress for a long time but have never run into this situation, it's kicking my butt.

Any help would be appreciate, thank you for your time and effort.

*Update* I have the individual templates for the pages. And have looked into the conditional tags which will help for sure. I'm building this for a client who is new to Wordpress so I want to make the process very easy for them. They need to be able to post these slides themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your options are to hook the slider into the page/post media gallery using something like  get_children or get_posts attachments. Another option is to use a custom "image" field for the slider images and query them using query_posts.

Comment: Sounds fun, I've never done that. Any resources that you know of that could help me get started?  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Certain which page types? In general [Conditional Tags > A PAGE Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page) allows to easily check for plenty of stuff.

You can also easily create individual [templates for pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display) if they must be quite different from the rest.

Comment: I have the individual templates for the pages. And have looked into the conditional tags which will help for sure. I'm building this for a client who knows pretty new to Wordpress so I want to make the process very easy for them.